# Function outside of ngOnInit calls function inside the ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to have something like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
  ...
  function test() {
    ...
  }
}

function()
{
  test();
}
```

If this possible, then how?

Comment: this is not possible you cannot have a function inside function

Comment: @RahulSingh Not true. Perfectly valid to have nested functions.

Comment: @Saravana its possible i get it using function declaration. But not the moat elegant way.  Its then better to declare separate method takea away modularity i feel. It becomes a type of closure

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: @RahulSingh Huge difference between "not possible" and "not elegant".

Comment: @Saravana i take back my words for that. I was thinking in Angular way not JavaScript.

Comment: It's possible _and_ valid to do so. For example, you might pass in the function as an `@Input` and want to transform it before assigning it to another function. This is a very valid use-case.

Answer (score 2):

The function you define in `ngOnInit` needs to be stored somewhere in the class instance in order to call it again. That means that you need an attribute to store it in.

```
class Component {
  private fn: Function; // or a better type if you know it
}
```

Now, inside the `ngOnInit`, assign a function to this variable. You probably want to use an arrow function for `this` to be what you (probably) expect it to be.

```
class Component {
  private fn: Function; // or a better type if you know it

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fn = () => {} // create it here
  }
}
```

After this has happened, you can just call the `fn` function as usually, from anywhere.

```
this.fn()
```

Be careful though, if you try to execute the above line before the `OnInit` hook kicks in, you'll get a runtime error. For example, if you're using `fn` inside the `OnChanges` hook (which will be called once before the `OnInit` hook), you'll need to be careful:

```
if (this.fn) {
  this.fn()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you want to do something like that? But this is what would make it work :

Inside your component , declare a variable

```
func : any;
```

Then inside ngOnInit,

```
 ngOnInit(){
  ...
  func = function test() {
   ...
  }
}
```

Then to call the function inside another function in the same component use,

```
function someOtherFunction()
{
  this.func();
}
```

Comment: This is completely wrong. Firstly, you cannot declare an attribute in a class with `let`. There is no type `Any`, only `any`. If you create the `func` using the `function` syntax, you'll need to save reference to `this` -- you should use an arrow function instead. You cannot call a function with `function() { func () }`; this is a function definition, not a call.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, you are absolutely correct. I did not run the code . I meant  that you needed to use a class member variable to store an instance of the function that you defined in the ngOnInit() method so that you could invoke it from another function. I'll correct my answer

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, regarding your comment about having to save a reference to this, that is not correct so far as Typescript is concerned